# In Prod env Java batch Fails sometimes with NoClassdeffoundError due to class not found exception. Occurres atleast once in a day or a week

Tags: java

I am facing NoClassdeffoundError due to class not found exception for Java batch application.jar files are deployed on the windows server these batch jars are getting executed via bat file from Tivoli job schedular .But I am totally clueless why it is occurring only some times in a day or in week.This issue is not coming on QA Environment but on production it occurring.My logs are as follows

```
java.io.IOException: An unexpected network error occurred
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.writeToDestination(OutputStreamManager.java:256)
    ... 29 more

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils
    at com.xxx.yy.batch.BatchExecutor.processFiles(BatchExecutor.java:322)
    at com.xxx.yy.batch.BatchExecutor.processZipFiles(BatchExecutor.java:235)
    at com.xxx.yy.batch.BatchExecutor.readFilesAndUpdateTables(BatchExecutor.java:204)
    at com.xxx.yy.batch.BatchExecutor.executeBatch(BatchExecutor.java:85)
    at com.xxx.yy.batch.BatchExecutor.main(BatchExecutor.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/Java7Support
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.isSymlink(FileUtils.java:3089)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1574)
    at com.xxx.yy.batch.processor.BatchProcessor.cleanFiles(BatchProcessor.java:426)
    at com.xxx.yy.batch.BatchExecutor.executeBatch(BatchExecutor.java:147)
    at com.xxx.yy.batch.BatchExecutor.main(BatchExecutor.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.Java7Support
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

I confirmed that my class path is correct all the jars and classes are present.